# Installing "standalone" version of Wine to Ubuntu directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine, ironworker

I'm attempting to create an IronWorker and I'd like to use a Windows binary to run the task.  I believe that if I can create a standalone Wine executable in a subdirectory and reference it in my worker descriptor that I should be able to run the binary.  Every worker starts with a clean environment, so I don't want to reinstall Wine every time (the worker task is very short).

Has anybody successfully achieved this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use .deb files for that.
http://dev.iron.io/worker/reference/dotworker/#syntax_reference

You need Ubuntu 12.04 x64 packages.
Examples:

- lots of deb files: https://github.com/thousandsofthem/workers/tree/master/mono-3.0.6
- bring-your-own-binary https://github.com/iron-io/iron_worker_examples/tree/master/binary/phantomjs
- bring-your-own-binary simple version: https://github.com/thousandsofthem/workers/tree/master/ffmpeg

Comment: Gotcha.  I'll give it a shot and report back.  Thank you for the prompt response!